# How do I use local state along with redux store state in the same react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, react-redux

I have a table that displays contacts and I want to sort the contacts by first name. The contacts array comes from the redux store, which will come then come through the props, but I want the local state to hold how those contacts are sorted, since it's local UI state. How do I achieve this? I so far have placed contacts into `componentWillReceiveProps` but for some reason it doesn't receive the props when it changes. How do I update the local state each time the redux store state changes?

```
const Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {contacts: []}
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps () {
    this.setState({ contacts: this.props.data.contacts})
  },
  sortContacts (parameter, e){
    ...
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={this.sortContacts.bind(this, "firstName")}>First Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {contactRows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
})
```

**update of current code that includes filtering**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import TableRow from './TableRow'

class Table extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { sortBy: "fistName" }
  }
  sortContacts (parameter) {
    console.log('in sortContacts')

    this.setState({ sortBy: parameter })
  }
  sortedContacts () {
    console.log('in sortedContacts')

    const param = this.state.sortBy
    return (
      this.props.data.contacts.sort(function (a, b){
        if (!a.hasOwnProperty(param)){
          a[param] = " ";
        }
        if (!b.hasOwnProperty(param)){
          b[param] = " ";
        }
        const nameA = a[param].toLowerCase(), nameB = b[param].toLowerCase();
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      })
    )
  }
  filteredSortedContacts () {
    console.log('in filteredSortedContacts')

    const filterText = this.props.data.filterText.toLowerCase()
    let filteredContacts = this.sortedContacts()
    if (filterText.length > 0) {
      filteredContacts = filteredContacts.filter(function (contact){
        return (
          contact.hasOwnProperty('lastName') &&
          contact.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(filterText)
        )
      })
    }
    return filteredContacts
  }
  contactRows () {
    console.log('in contactRows')
    return this.filteredSortedContacts().map((contact, idx) =>
      <TableRow contact={contact} key={idx}/>
    )
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="table-container">
        <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="th-cell" onClick={this.sortContacts.bind(this, "firstName")}>First Name</th>
              <th onClick={this.sortContacts.bind(this, "lastName")}>Last Name</th>
              <th>Date of Birth</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.contactRows()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Table
```

The issue I'm seeing now is that `contactRows, filteredSortedContacts, sortedContacts` are being called multiple times, once for each TableRow. I don't see how this can be happening if I'm only calling `contactRows` once in the body.

Comment: Show reducer and content of `sortContants`.

Answer (score 10):

Your approach to use both redux store and local store is correct.

Just do not try to duplicate the state from redux store in your component. Keep referring to it via props.

Instead create a `sortedContacts` function that computes value on the fly by applying locally-stored `sortBy` param to redux-stored contacts.

```
const Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortBy: 'id' // default sort param
    }
  }

  sortContacts(param) {
    this.setState({ sortBy: param})
  }

  sortedContacts() {
    return this.props.contacts.sort(...); // return sorted collection
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={() => this.sortContacts("firstName")}>First Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.sortedContacts()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is cool! So instead of having local state hold a sorted array of contacts, you have it hold the parameter needed to do the sorting. When this parameter changes, will it still cause a automatic re-rendering that will in turn call #sortedContacts again? I thought the auto re-render only happens when state changes and there is something in the state that needs to be rendered, not a method that is dependent on the state changing.

Comment: why is it better to do this than to make a duplicate of the redux state and sort it?

Comment: Because if you have just one source of truth you don't need any synchronization code. In your case you could easily apply not only sorting, but also filtering, transformation etc in the same way.

Comment: can you look at my update and see if you know why i'm getting multiple runs of the sort methods?

Comment: @MichałSzajbe good point on one source of truth. the only thing I'm concerned is if I have 1000 rows — won't this approach sort everytime the component renders though? say I have pagination, everytime I click `next`, it will resort 1000 data CMIIW. is there better approach to this?

Comment: @yonasstephen I think this may be a concern only if you render the same component multiple times (e.g. in multiple places). In normal situations when the props change you'd need to re-sort anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `componentWillReceiveProps()` method is not called for the initial render. What could do, if you only intend to use the data from props as the initial data, is something like:

```
getInitialState () {
  return {
    contacts: this.props.data.contacts
  }
}
```

In the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) they suggest you name the props initialContacts, just to make it really clear that the props' only purpose is to initialize something internally.

Now if you want it to update when `this.props.contacts` change, you could use `componentWillReceiveProps()` like you did. But I'm not sure it's the best idea. From the docs:

> Using props to generate state in getInitialState often leads to
>   duplication of "source of truth", i.e. where the real data is. This is
>   because getInitialState is only invoked when the component is first
>   created.
>
> Whenever possible, compute values on-the-fly to ensure that they don't
>   get out of sync later on and cause maintenance trouble.

Answer (score 1):

React 16.3 includes a static function `getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)`, which will be invoked after initial mount as well as when it receives new props. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: It is not always fired on prop change, if the prop does not call a render it will not be fired. This is because its called before a invoked render method and not after initial mount technically.