# Why shouldn't you store redux store state in your local component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I had previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992000/how-do-i-use-local-state-along-with-redux-store-state-in-the-same-react-componen?noredirect=1#comment67263198_39992000) on react component state working in conjunction with Redux state. The first chain of code below is my original proposal for solving the issue, and the 2nd is an answer I got suggesting that I don't make a duplicate of the redux state. Is this because it's slow to make a duplicate? And it's faster to just store as less as possible in the local state and then the JS take care of the sorting?

On a related note, it feels weird that the 2nd chain of code requires me to always use functions that will return objects. Is this the only way to go? I know that in `React.createClass` you can store variables to hold objects and such, but with es6's extend component version, seems like you must use functions. Is there a way around this or is that just the way it is?

```
const Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {contacts: []}
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps () {
    this.setState({ contacts: this.props.data.contacts})
  },
  sortContacts (parameter, e){
    ...
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={this.sortContacts.bind(this, "firstName")}>First Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {contactRows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
})
```

vs.

```
const Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sortBy: 'id' // default sort param
    }
  }

  sortContacts(param) {
    this.setState({ sortBy: param})
  }

  sortedContacts() {
    return this.props.contacts.sort(...); // return sorted collection
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={() => this.sortContacts("firstName")}>First Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.sortedContacts()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is related to the Redux store but the code presented is React.js only code with no implementation of Redux store at all.

Answer (score 0):

first let me clear your doubt, when you should use React Component State,

1. if something get stored only for the time when component is active, use react state.
2. if you want someone to see same ui for the component as they left before, even when then return after performing some other operations on other component use Redux.

Now about your Data Filtering
we use both  State and Redux..

1. we use state to filter data from name, because we don't want him to see same filtered data when he returns to page, because that creates confusion
2. for filtering data on price or some other filters we store the actual data  and filters data in Redux.
3. since we store actual data in redux and filters, we apply filter algorithm just before data is sent to component i.e. in MapStateToProps.
   e.g.  data: getFilteredData(state.somestate.data, state.somestate.filters)
   where getFilteredData is a function which accepts the data and filters and returns filtered data

Answer (score 0):

There's no Redux in your code and your issue seems to not be a Redux related.

The second code block uses ES6 classes. Google it to find out what you can do with them.

In Redux, components should preferably be stateless. They receive data from Redux or from parent and store nothing at all. So no `setState`. The Table would not sort anything (it would receive sorted days as a prop), or maybe it would but it wouldn't be state, it would sort it in the `render`. Of course it would sort a copy, not the incoming `prop`.

These things sound crazy, sure. Sorry on every render? What about performance, people!? The answer is memoization. Use selectors (reselect package).

The reason for storing every bit of data in Redux is: single source of truth. It allows time travel and hot reloading. Logging. State save/restore. It prevents disagreements on which data is current or correct. There's more but it's too much for this question.