# How to mix React and Redux state/store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to React and Redux, and after having some fun with docs i'm a little confused with real world example.

I have component Table and its children TableRow in it.

Table connected to store with users array and displays all users. TableRow displays user's first and last name. Also TableRow have action column with buttons "update" and "delete". Deleting button should remove user and its row. Updating button implement inline editing when first and last names become input fields and action column has "save" and "cancel" buttons.

Sooooo, obvious TableRow has its own internal state to handle buttons display, for example. But also deleting or updating actions should be part of Redux to affect store data.

The question is Is it okay to mix internal state + Redux store + Redux actions and reducers?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992000/how-do-i-use-local-state-along-with-redux-store-state-in-the-same-react-componen

Comment: First you have to do a simple app using redux store. Redux actions and reducers are not different state managements. They are just a part of Redux.

Comment: @HardikModha it looks like related question, but in my case i'd like to connect dispatch actions to TableRow and i'm not sure about it (is it ok or not)

Comment: @HenokTesfaye i understand that Redux actions and reducers are parts of Redux

Comment: @HenokTesfaye TBH, They are not exactly part of the redux. They just help to complete the flow. You can use actions and reducers even when not using redux. No one's gonna stop you. You can go through this very famous article. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Comment: Yes @Hardik. I'm just taking from redux context. Actions are literal js objects and Reducers are functions that accept a literal object(state) and that return a new object with out mutating the passed object.

Comment: Finally @AntonAbramov. If you use redux for data management you may also use local state to manage the ui like condition that you faced.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye ok, but is it ok to integrate dispatching like connect(null,mapDispatchToProps) to TableRow in my example?

Comment: It's totally fine.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to connect to redux. mapDispatchToProps gives you an interface to dispatch an action. But before doing anything else I would recommend you to study about HOC then connect.js explained by Dan abramov. It is just a mental map of how does connect works.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye could you share the link to read about all this stuff by Dan?

Comment: Here u go, https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e

Comment: Also check the source code of redux it is really simple and easy to understand.